# Command line arguments R script using Tinn-R

Tags: r

How can I use command line arguments with a R script using Tinn-R.

I can give arguments with a R script like this:

```
R.exe --args 2010 test.R
```

And after that read them in the script with `commandArgs`.

But how can I provide them when using Tinn-R? I cannot find anything in the Tinn-R help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

[SourceForge - Helppages for Tinn](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinn-r/forums/forum/481901/topic/4425368/index/page/1)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Maybe I'm doing someting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Give a looked in the picture attached below.
I think it should solve your question.

[image: parameters]